# JS Axios - how to get response body in event of error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, axios

I want to be able to get the response body back from an Axios error catch.

I am using axios v0.18.0.

My axios code looks like this:

```
let service = axios.create({
                baseURL: "https://baseUrl.azurewebsites.net",
                responseType: "json"
            });

        service.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;

        service.post("/api/method", params).then(result => {
            console.log('success',result);
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log('error');
            console.log(error);
        });
```

My API call is returning a 400 error as I expected, given my inputs. So I am hitting the catch block. However I'm not able to retrieve the error message that's returned by the API call.

I've tried doing a console.out(error.response.data), but this returns null.

I've verified using Postman that the API call *does* return an error message in the response body, so the API isn't the problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I tested it with [Mocky](https://www.mocky.io/) and the error message is indeed returned in `error.response.data`.

```
const axios = require('axios');

// http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c06f6be3000009600d25953 (the mock api to call, it always returns 400 with an error message)

let service = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://www.mocky.io",
    responseType: "json"
});

service.post("/v2/5c06f6be3000009600d25953").then(result => {
    console.log('success', result);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
});
```

The code above prints `Ooops, bad request!`, as returned.

EDIT: apparently the problem you described can happen for a variety of reasons. See [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960) issue.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I ran your code about but don't see the "Ooops, bad request!" being returned; I get "null". I also read the link you referenced. There's a comment from jacurtis (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960#issuecomment-398269712)  about having to look into error.response.data or error.response.data.data, but these are both non-null.

Comment: Strange... I made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQbrpR?editors=1111) and the same problem occurs. But if I run locally with Node it works.

Comment: To amend my earlier comment ... I meant to say that error.response.data and error.response.data.data *are both null*. So there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to get the error response.

Comment: Axios automatically reads the body for 400 but not 500, I was looking for a way to configure that...

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to fix the problem.

```
let options = {
    baseURL: "http://www.mocky.io",
    responseType: "application/json"
};

//service.post("/v2/5c06f6be3000009600d25953",{}).then(result => {
axios.post("/v2/5c06f6be3000009600d25953",null,options).then(result => {
    console.log('success', result);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response);
});
```

The main modification was to change "responseType" to "**application/json**".

Thanks for your help everyone.